# Certain validations only in Rails.env.production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to only allow certain validations within `production` vs other environments for an app.

For example, I have tried to add:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  validates :email, :uniqueness => true
  validates :phone, :uniqueness => true
end
```

However this will not work.  **How can one add validations only to specific environment modes?**

Comment: I think this is generally a very bad idea. What is your reasoning for wanting to do this?

Comment: In certain development cases we have a limited number of telephone numbers to test with.  We would like to be able to register test users with the same telephone number, however in production this is not allowed.  This is a rather innocuous scenario and should not be a problem whatsoever to do such a thing.

Comment: So generate some telephone numbers with dummy gem, what's the problem? Or just comment out that lines while in development.

Comment: @ylluminate Then use factories or fixtures or something similar to generate the data you need. Having your development environment differ in this way from your production is not a good idea.

Comment: I do appreciate the suggestions, thanks.  I would prefer to know how to do this.  It seems as though it should be doable regardless of whether it's a bad idea or not.  Thanks!

Comment: Your code should work even though it's not a good idea. Are you able to create records with the same email on production without errors?

Comment: as you can see folks hate spending time giving details on bad advice!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this -

```
validates :email, :uniqueness => true, :if => lambda{ Rails.env.production?}
validates :phone, :uniqueness => true, :if => lambda{ Rails.env.production?}
```

Answer (score 2):

Totally agree with the comments, but if you really want to do this, try the :if option

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email, :if => Rails.env.production?
```